# Solving for the limit of a Gaussian random variable within an integral

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals, normal-distribution

I'm having trouble solving a particular integral.  It is

$$
(1/\Delta t)\int_t^{t+\Delta t}I(t')dt',
$$

where

$$
I(t') = \mu_c+\sigma_c \eta(t').
$$

In this second equation,

$$
\eta(t') = \lim_{dt\to0}N(0, 1/\sqrt{dt}),
$$

where $N(\alpha, \beta)$ is a Gaussian random variable of mean $\alpha$ and variance $\beta^2$.

The variables I haven't defined are all constants.  Can anyone help me out?  It's really that limit I'm having trouble with.  A numerical solution is as good as an analytical one as far as I'm concerned.

This integral comes from [this book chapter](http://nba.uth.tmc.edu/homepage/cnjclub/2007summer/renart_chapter.pdf).  Specifically, it is part of the "diffusion approximation" described in Section 15.2.3, which begins on page 436.  I'm trying to replicate the line on the right side of Figure 15.1B (page 440), the definition of which is given in the figure caption on page 441.

Comment: So your $\eta$ is white noise? This limit doesn't exist in the conventional sense, so you have to be careful with how you use it.

Comment: @Ian exactly.  actually, according to the paper i'm working from, the definition for it i gave in the question is only a "heuristic" definition.  i'm going to link to the specific section of the paper that's relevant in my question.

Comment: I think that what is intended is that $\eta$ should have the property that $W(T)=\int_0^T \eta(t) dt$ is the Wiener process, also called (in mathematical circles) Brownian motion.

Comment: @Ian OK, so it sounds like i should try to implement a white noise process computationally, and then solve the integral numerically.  is there any other work we can do on this with pure math?  or, more generally, do you have any recommendations?

Comment: @Ian i guess i'm still not sure how to define the white noise process such that it's amenable to computational analysis.  for example, i have a function that returns a Gaussian random process provided a mean and SD.  what would i pass it as an SD in this case?  infinity?  that doesn't seem like it would get me what i need, but i'm not sure how else to interpret the limit in my question.

Comment: You use a large but finite variance instead, and set the time step accordingly.

Comment: @Ian ah, OK, so i guess it is as simple as that.  i thought the interpretation of that limit as implying N(0, infinity) might have been too simplistic.  (what purpose is the square root in the SD serving?  i guess it's just to say that the *variance* is infinity, the SD the square root of infinity (i.e., also infinity)?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27444/discussion-between-dbliss-and-ian).

Comment: The gist of it: the Wiener process $W(t)$ is a stochastic process satisfying $W(0)=0,E[W(t)]=0,E[W(t)^2]=t$, and which has independent increments, meaning that $W(b)-W(a)$ is independent of $W(d)-W(c)$ if $a<b<c<d$. The trajectories of this process are nowhere differentiable with probability 1, which means that your $\eta$ ("white noise") does not exist in any pathwise sense. However, we can numerically approximate the Wiener process by adding up a bunch of independent normal variables, multiplied by time steps in such a way that the resulting approximation has variance $t$.

Comment: Specifically, $W(t) \approx \sum_{i=1}^n N_i$, where $N_i$ are iid normals with mean zero and variance $\frac{t}{n}$. Equivalently we can write $W(t) \approx \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{t}{n} M_i$, where $M_i$ are iid normals with mean zero and variance $\frac{n}{t}$. You can fill in the gaps with linear interpolation. The $M_i$ are the analogue of "white noise".